# Enable wake-up from sleep mode through GPIO signal

Tags: linux, arm, gpio

I need to wake up my BeagleBone device, running Angstrom OS, from sleep mode through GPIO signal.

I read that using `/sys/class/gpio/gpioXX/power/wakeup` is the way to do. The problem is that there isn't any "wakeup" file under power directory. So, how I should proceed to activate it? Is there any solution without recompiling kernel?

I can read fine from GPIO value, so GPIO sysfs is working.

Comment: On other OMAPxx series processors (or derivatives), only the first bank of GPIOs (a bank is 32 bits) has wake-up capability - presumably done for power-management reasons, as otherwise, the entire GPIO unit would need to be in a powered state during sleep.

Comment: The port I'm using is GPIO0_7, so it is in the first bank and it seems as if I have to configure something to enable it. Am I on track?

Comment: I think at this point it's time to dig around in the kernel source tree.  You may well need to recompile it. Looks as though the BeagleBone kernel is build with the BeagleBoard's defConfig, so poke around `mux.c` and `mux.h` in arch `/arm/mach-omap2/` in the source tree.  I'd also check in the user manual whether the device can be woken from that pin.

Comment: May be BeagleBone board hasn't any GPIO lines to processor's WAKEUP signal connection?

Answer (score 2):

There was issue inside GPIO driver in OMAP4xxx kernel, when GPIO banks was initialized *before* mux subsystem initialisation. This effectively prevented wakeups by pins in GPIO mode.

You can check this, by reading `mux[]` fields of struct `gpio_bank` (file drivers/omap/gpio-omap.c). They should not hold NULL values.

There is a for loop at end of `void omap_gpio_mod_init(struct gpio_bank *bank)` function. 
You need to remove it, and initialize `mux` pointer at end of `static int omap_gpio_request(struct gpio_chip *chip, unsigned offset)` function.

This will ensure, that it will be inited correctly.

Also, as far as I remember, the was some issue with debounce clocks. If my first advice wont work, try to disable debounce for that pin.